# How to cal this API in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have one query I am not able to call this API my Query annotation is not able to append in the URL

http://api.trendbee.io/outlet-products?product_category.id_eq=1

I am using this code in my android interface:

```
@GET("outlet-products") //this is my get API code
Call <List<BrowseCategoryPojo>> productCategoriesDetails(@Query("product_category.id_eq") String id);
```

Comment: what the error occurred ?

Comment: Did you enable cleartexttraffic in manifest? That url is http instead of https